# PyCharm launching Django console for Flask app

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

For whatever reason, PyCharm thinks my Flask project is a Django project, and thus launches a Django console instead of a Python console in the toolbar:

[image]

The project interpreter is configured properly:

[image]

Here is my project hierarchy, if it's relevant：

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── email.py
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── errors.py
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── favicon.ico
│   └── templates
│       ├── 404.html
│       ├── 500.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── index.html
│       └── mail
│           ├── new_user.html
│           └── new_user.txt
├── config.py
├── data-dev.sqlite
├── data-test.sqlite
├── manage.py
├── migrations
│   ├── README
│   ├── alembic.ini
│   ├── env.py
│   ├── script.py.mako
│   └── versions
│       ├── 38c4e85512a9_initial_migration.py
├── requirements.txt
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_basics.py
```

Just because there is a module called `manage.py` doesn't mean I'm working on a Django project!

How can I fix this?

Comment: What are the settings under: **PyCharm > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console** for current project? I only see Python Console as an option. Maybe [these docs will help?](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-console.html)

Comment: [It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks1LH.png). Thanks for your link to the docs. Now I'm trying to figure out how to change the project type from Django to Flask.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @atwalsh Nope :(

Answer (score 7):

You can disable Django support for your project here:

**Settings > Language & Frameworks > Django**

Comment: Its Settings, not Preferences. Just a minor issue. This worked for me.